# Find highest number with trailing 9's in a range

Tags: c++, for-loop, testing

I want to find the highest number with the most trailing 9's in a range of min and max. The lowest a number in any range can be is 0, and the max is 3,000,000,000 thus I am using `size_t`. Our test cases:

case 1: min = 460, max = 680, answer = 599

case 2: min = 18696, max = 18702, answer = 18699

case 3: min = 1255, max = 2999, answer = 2999

The last test input (case 3) is working just fine, but the others are not passing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    size_t min = 460;
    size_t max = 680;
    size_t answer= max;
    size_t tempAnswer = max;
    size_t tempMax = max; // temporary placeholder to not modify max
    size_t lastDigit = 0;
    size_t tempLook = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // following variable gets the length of number (ex: 3000 = 3) if we add 1 to function call we get the real length, but we dont need the first digit.
    int sizeOfMax = static_cast<int>(std::floor(std::log10(max)));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfMax; i++)
    {
        lastDigit = tempMax % 10; // looks at last digit in max

        if (lastDigit == 9)
        {
            count++;
            tempMax = tempMax / 10;
        }
        else {
            for (int j = count; j > 0; j--)
            {
                tempMax *= 10;
                tempLook = max % 10;
                tempMax += tempLook;
            }

            if (count != sizeOfMax - count)
            {
                count = 0;
                tempMax -= 1;
                tempAnswer = tempMax;
                i = -1;
            }
        }

        if (answer < min)
        {
            answer = max;
        }
        else {
            answer = tempAnswer;
        }
    }

    printf("%zi", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried modifying the code slightly above if the `lastDigit` isn't 9, but it throws my answers off wildly.

Comment: Are there actual limits on how big the numbers can be? You're using `std::size_t`, but is that big enough? Programming challenges are typically explicit about constraints, which often gives clues as to the solution.

Comment: yes, sorry, the maximum a number can be is 3,000,000,000
the minimum is 0

Comment: Your arithmetic makes no sense to me. E.g. `if (count != sizeOfMax - count)` - this is equivalent to `if (2*count != sizeOfMax)` Why is it significant that `count` be equal to half of `sizeOfMax`? What if `sizeOfMax` is odd - then this condition would always be true.

Comment: I'm not sure what my thinking on that was. I think i was getting wildly different numbers than when i included the if statement you mentioned, and when i added this in (thinking that it would account for odd numbers) it started working with some of our other random test cases.

Comment: Adding some debug statements will help you examine whether your program is behaving the way you expect: https://godbolt.org/z/qY8q1Kocz -- to me, this looks pretty wild.

Comment: i am new to programming, especially with c++, so i know i have a long way to go before i can start answering challenges the preferred way, or even in an intelligible way lmao.

Comment: To say "please correct", you should explain about your algorithm. Understanding what really you want to do (:your algorithm) from not working code only is very hard and tired.

Comment: Tactical note: Learning C++ via coding challenges is one of the slowest ways to learn the language, and typically what you wind up learning is... Not that good. Kinda like deciding to learn to box by entering prize fights. You'd spend too much time unconscious on the mat to pick up the finer points of the art. I strongly recommend reading your way through [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301) or two, doing the exercises, and learning in a controlled manner. Even Stack Overflow's not much help if you know too little.

Comment: Your approach is way too complicated.  You're also using floating point (danger, Will Robinson!) to calculate (`sizeOfMax`) when a simple loop with integral division by `10` will suffice.   A simpler logic than you're using would be to calculate `max%(10^(sizeOfMax - 1)) - 1` (where I'm using `^` for exponentiation) as a first guess for the value with maximum number of trailing nines.  Then decrement `sizeOfMax` while the guess is less than the `min` and stop if `sizeOfMax` reaches zero (no values with trailing 9s in the range).

Comment: Why did you choose 2999 as the answer for case 3 over 1999?  Both are in the range and end with 3 nines.  Your algorithm seems overly complicated.

Comment: @MarkRansom the description calls for the "highest number with the most trailing 9's"

Comment: highest number with most leading 9 is two things to maximize and the weighting is undefined. Why is case 2 not 9999 ? why is case 1 not 679 ? Once you sacrifice a trailing 9 for a bigger number, the other time you do the opposite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't wrap my head around your algorithm, or I was unwilling to because it just isn't intuitive. Without useful variable names and/or a sensible description of how it's supposed to work, even this small amount of code is too much cognitive load for me today.

So, instead I had a think about how I would do this, as a human. This is often a very useful way to think about problems. Your brain does clever things all the time. Try to become conscious of what it's really doing when you're thinking about how to find the answer on paper.

For me, it was straight-forward. I noticed my brain wanted to turn every digit of `max` starting from the right into a 9, until it's not possible because I've gone below the minimum value. That's the entire algorithm.

So, how to represent that in code?

To begin, I want to know the value of a '1' digit in each position. That means advancing through powers of 10. So, first I look at the 1, then 10, 100, 1000... To work out what digit actual digit lives there, just divide and take the modulo 10.

```
size_t power = 1;
while (power < max)
{
    int digit = (max / power) % 10;
    if (digit == 9) {
        power *= 10;          // advance to next digit
    }
}
```

Great, but this doesn't do anything yet, beyond walk through all the 9s. Let's think about the other bit: If we don't have a 9, then how do we make one?

Well, a simple way is to just subtract 1 from that digit, handle any carries and see if you ticked-over, right? Let's do that -- it's maybe not the most efficient, but it's the easiest and it's fine.

The maximum number of times we'll subtract 1 from any single digit is gonna be 9. The loop is therefore constrained to run a maximum of 9 times the number of digits. No worries -- the time complexity is still considered linear.

```
size_t answer = max;
size_t power = 1;
while (power < max)
{
    int digit = (max / power) % 10;
    if (digit == 9) {
        power *= 10;
        answer = max;         // this answer is same or better than previous
    } else {
        max -= power;         // subtract 1 from digit at this position
    }
}
```

Now, this is very nearly all you need to do. The last bit of the puzzle is to ensure that when you subtract, you don't end up below the valid range. You could check if `max - power >= min`, but there's a little 'gotcha' here because your unsigned values *can* wrap around if you subtract a value that would normally result in a negative. If that happened, the condition would always be true and you could loop forever! :(

The good news, is you can prevent such a disaster by rearranging that equation: it's equivalent to `max >= min + power`. You're not gonna wrap `min` around "below" zero this way, so it's safe.

```
size_t answer = max;
size_t power = 1;
while (power < max)
{
    int digit = (max / power) % 10;
    if (digit == 9) {
        power *= 10;
        answer = max;
    } else if (max >= min + power) {  // is decreasing digit still in range?
        max -= power;
    } else {
        break;                        // finished
    }
}
```

And that's all there is to it! We started by tapping into the guidance and wisdom of our own intuition, and the rest was just translating that into code.

Comment: incredible! my brain just doesn't work this way. I tend to over complicate EVERYTHING. I obviously have a lot to learn, mainly how to think like a programmer. Thank you so much for the explanation. 

What would you suggest I study so that challenges like this come more intuitively? I understand that it may just be the way I process and approach these challenges that needs to change.

Comment: my approach was basically to look at every digit from right to left, and subtract the ENTIRE max number by 1 each time the digit wasn't a 9.

i also tried to steer away from using 'break' in any kind of loop because i was taught that it was bad practice and extremely frowned upon

Comment: Don't worry too much if algorithm-oriented intuition and translation into code doesn't come easily. I've had a bit more practice than you (wrote my first program in 1988). Just keep at it. Sounds like you were on a similar approach here, but the code did not make that at all obvious. Regarding the `break`, yes it's good to avoid. I put it there for simplicity. It's the last line in the loop, so it's clear. Setting `power = max;` to end the loop would work. That's ugly, I think. Or create a "done" flag, which would just add clutter. There's general rules, yes. But there are usually exceptions.

Answer (score -2):

I can not read what you really want to do (your algorithm) from your code. (it seems too complex)

But... perhaps, it looks like bellow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

//Extract the value of target digit.
//ex) Extract( 13847, 100 ) returns 8.
inline int Extract( size_t Val, size_t D )
{   return ( Val % (D*10) ) / D;    }

//Change the value of target digit.
//ex) Change( 13847, 1000, 9 ) return 19847.
inline size_t Change( size_t Val, size_t D, int Dx )
{   return Val - D*Extract(Val,D) + D*Dx;   }

//
size_t Test( size_t min, size_t max )
{
    int nDigits = static_cast<int>( std::log10(max) + 1 );

    //ex) if max= 18702, Ans initialized as 99999.
    size_t Ans = pow( 10, nDigits ) - 1;

    //ex) if max= 18702, D initialized as 10000.
    size_t D = pow( 10, nDigits-1 );
    while( D >= 1 )
    {
        for( int Dx=Extract(max,D); Dx>=Extract(min,D); --Dx )
        {
            Ans = Change( Ans, D, Dx );
            if( Ans <= max )return Ans; //Answer found
        }
        D /= 10;    //to next digit
    }

    return 0;  //will not reach here (?)
}

//
int main()
{
    std::cout << Test( 460, 680 ) << std::endl; //599
    std::cout << Test( 18696, 18702 ) << std::endl; //18699
    std::cout << Test( 1255, 2999 ) << std::endl;   //2999
    return 0;
}
```

I can not understand meaning of all claimed points... but, only the point "code-only without any explanation" may be able to be improved by this edit.

The way I indicated with above code is:

Considering  to start from the value which all digits are 9.
(Number of digits equals to the `max`.)
For example, if `max` is 18702, starting from 99999 (as shown comment in code).

Of cause this value is not answer excpting the `max = 99999` situation, but obviously the value of the most significant digit of the answer is between that digit of `min` and `max`.

Therefore, assuing the remaining digits of the answer are all 9, then if check the most significant digits in order from the largest(`max`'s ) to the lowest(`min`'s), the answer is the first one found.

The case answer can not be found is only the situation `min`'s and `max`'s is same; and in this case, we got the significant digit value of answer, what to do is step to next digit and trying same procedure.

e.g.

> case 1: min = 460, max = 680, answer = 599

Checking from **6**99 to **4**99 --> 599 found.

> case 2: min = 18696, max = 18702, answer = 18699

- Checking from **1**9999 to **1**9999 --> answer not found. but we know the answer is 1XXXX.
- Checking from 1**8**999 to 1**8**999 --> answer not found. but we know the answer is 18XXX.
- Checking from 18**7**99 to 18**6**99 --> 18699 found.

Comment: I added `<iostream>` only because it is enough for my env. But may be, it depends on implementation of `iostream` header(Perhaps for some other env, needed to write `#include <cmath>` etc.)

Comment: OK, I added `<cmath>`.
I don't know the criteria about this(which headers should be indicated explicitly into posted code) of this site.
But, in other hand, it looks like that, my post don't be owned exclusively by me. So, if you think it can be better, please edit rather than request/claim.

Comment: Let's get real for a moment. You've provided a code-only answer without any explanation of the approach. You're using floating-point functions for integer operations, the code comments don't make sense, the formatting is inconsistent, the style doesn't follow the author's style, and the only actual comment you make about any of this is written as a question. If I was to theorize, any downvote is more likely to be related to one or more of these things, and nothing to do with a missing include. I'd be quite tempted to downvote this myself. Voting is a feedback mechanism, not an insult.

Comment: @paddy Thank you for your indication. I understood there is many hated point, yes. But the point using `std::log10` is from original code.

Comment: If you're going to throw their code away and rewrite your own algorithm, you may as well use good practices while you're at it. Explain what you're doing and why. That's how to actually help somebody. They are struggling with their own code, so you can't expect them to understand what you've done if you just code-dump a program that looks completely different from theirs.

Comment: I tried to explain.
Regarding the writing style etc, if it is really necessary, please feel free to make any necessary corrections.

Comment: @Retired Ninja : You gave me the chance to know `iostream` stipulated as include `ios, istream, ostream, and streambuf`. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, added explain then this post was downvoted. (Again!) But I strongly believe I have no ability to edit this post any further, so, I make no edit.